# form doesn't work in laravel 7, nothing happened

Tags: php, database, laravel

i try to add radio in register form. For when someone want to register he need to choice if its man or woman and when i try to register its not work dont save in database and nothing happened
Someone can helping me add the radio for choice man or woman.
when i want to register, nothing happens, neither in the database and on the page

create user table :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->id();
           $table->string('firstname');
           $table->string('email')->unique();
           $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
           $table->string('password');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->date('created_at');
           $table->string('address');
           $table->string('city');
           $table->string('zipcode');
           $table->string('gender');
           $table->string('number')->unique();
           $table->date('birthday');
           $table->string('pseudo')->unique();
           $table->rememberToken();
       });
   }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists('users');
       $table->dropColumn('gender');
   }
}
```

user.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'birthday', 'email', 'password', 'firstname', 'address', 'city', 'zipcode', 'gender', 'number', 'pseudo',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Register controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'city' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'zipcode' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'birthday' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'before:today'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'pseudo' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'unique:users'],
            'number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'unique:users'],
            'gender' => ['required', 'string'],

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'number' => $data['number'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'pseudo' => $data['pseudo'],

            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

register blade php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Firstname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required autocomplete="firstname" autofocus>

                                @error('firstname')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control @error('address') is-invalid @enderror" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autocomplete="address" autofocus>

                                @error('address')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="city" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('city') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control @error('city') is-invalid @enderror" name="city" value="{{ old('city') }}" required autocomplete="city" autofocus>

                                @error('city')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="zipcode" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('zipcode') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="zipcode" type="text" class="form-control @error('zipcode') is-invalid @enderror" name="zipcode" value="{{ old('zipcode') }}" required autocomplete="zipcode" autofocus>

                                @error('zipcode')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="number" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('number') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="number" type="text" class="form-control @error('number') is-invalid @enderror" name="number" value="{{ old('number') }}" required autocomplete="number" autofocus>

                                @error('number')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="birthday" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('birthday') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="birthday" type="date" class="form-control @error('birthday') is-invalid @enderror" name="birthday" value="{{ old('birthday') }}" required autocomplete="birthday" autofocus>

                                @error('birthday')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div id="gender-group" class="form-group{{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="gender" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Gender') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div><input id="female" type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="Female"> {{ (old('sex') == 'female') ? 'checked' : '' }} >Female</div>
                                    <div><input id="male" type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="Male"> {{ (old('sex') == 'male') ? 'checked' : '' }} >Male</div>
                                    @error('gender')
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::view('/', 'pages.home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Someone can talk where is my error ?

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: when i want to register, nothing happens, neither in the database and on the page

Comment: Post your route too

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that your field is named "gender" and you are calling `old('sex')`

After that, you are creating a new User, but you are not redirecting anywhere, causing this "blank" screen. As far as I can see there's no "register" route in your routes file

Comment: ok it's mean i need leave this : value="Male"> {{ (old('sex') == 'male') ? 'checked' : '' }} >Male if yes i replace with what?

Comment: i replaced by     <div><input id="male" type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="Male"> Male</div>